# Drupal 7: Views: Display content based on related taxonomy and user field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to create a complex view using Drupal 7.8, Views 7.x-3.0-rc1, and References 7.x-2.x-dev.

The Drupal instance contains the following:

Vocab:

- Zip Code: terms are a list of zip code with a taxonomy reference field to 'Hardiness Zones'
- Hardiness Zones: terms are a list of Hardiness Zones

Content Type:

- Plants: content contains taxonomy reference field to 'Hardiness Zones' (more than one).

User:

- Zip Code (Taxonomy Reference Field): users selects their Zip Code from the taxonomy 'Zip Codes' (user can only select one at the moment).

I'm calling the view 'my location'. I want it to show me "Plants" that have a matching "Hardiness Zone" to the User's "Zip Code".

I tried creating a user view (did not work) with:

- contextual filter for current user's 'zip code'
- advanced filter to show 'hardiness zones' for 'zip code'
- advanced filter to only show nodes with 'hardiness zones' from 'hardiness zones'

I might be getting some factors wrong or the whole dang thing, would anyone be able to advise? Should I be approaching this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not want it to be "fancy" :) You could just expose the zip code filter and allow the user to enter it manually. This would also help if they wanted to find the plants for another location.